# Django - getting object by its related fields' IDs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's assume we have following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Zomg(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

In `Zomg` model `foo` and `bar` fields serve as composite key, that is, for any pair of (`foo`, `bar`) there is only one `Zomg` object.

In my project I need to update thousands of `Zomg` records from time to time, so efficiency of finding records is important. The problem is that I cannot just pass `foo_id` and `bar_id` to `Zomg.objects.get()` method:

```
>>> z = models.Zomg.objects.get(foo_id=1, bar_id=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 550, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1069, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1260, in setup_joins
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'foo_id' into field. Choices are: bar, foo, id
```

However, when the object is instantiated `foo_id` and `bar_id` are pretty much accessible:

```
>>> z.foo_id
1
>>> z.bar_id
1
```

Now I'm forced to get `Foo` and `Bar` objects first and then use them to get the required `Zomg` object, making two unnecessary database queries:

```
>>> f = models.Foo.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b = models.Bar.objects.get(id=1)
>>> z = models.Zomg.objects.get(foo=f, bar=b)
```

So the question is, how can I get `Zomg` object by its related fields' IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`z = models.Zomg.objects.get(foo__id=1, bar__id=1)`

Comment: Thank you, so easy and works like a charm! Too bad that I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: To explain. In django you can access sub models by using the `__` syntax. foo itself is a reference to the Foo model, not the Foo model itself.To access the parts of the Foo model itself, use the `foo__` syntax. so you could search by name by simply `foo__name='Joe'`