# Django ORM - Create an alias of select_retaled field in values()

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to rename the unreadable field `agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__merchandise_unique_id` into `some_alias` using `extra`, but get `Uknown column "agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__merchandise_unique_id"` error, and yet if I don't use any alias, all is ok. What am I doing wrong ? Can I use `extra` with `select_selected` whatsoever ?

```
orders_qs = Order.objects.select_related('agreement_vendors_merchandise_list')\
         .extra(select={'some_alias': 'agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__merchandise_unique_id'})\
         .values('some_alias')
```

The model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   agreement_vendors_merchandise_list = models.ForeignKey(AgreementVendorsMerchandiseList, 
              on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
              related_name = 'agreement_vendors_merchandise_list')

class AgreementVendorsMerchandiseList(models.Model):
    merchandise_unique = models.ForeignKey(MerchandiseUnique, 
              on_delete = models.CASCADE,
              related_name = 'pricelist_merchandise_unique')
```

UPDATE:

This code (without alias) works perfect:

```
orders_qs = Order.objects.select_related('agreement_vendors_merchandise_list')\
.values('agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__merchandise_unique_id')
```

Comment: unique__id double underscore.

Comment: Your field is called merchandise_unique. Not merchandise_unique_id. If you need to get IDs of this field in your extra query, then it should be merchandise_unique__id. If not then just the name of related field.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't agree with you

Comment: merchandise_unique = models.ForeignKey(MerchandiseUnique) — that's your code. Not mine. You're trying to select a field that doesn't exist on the model. Hence the error.

Comment: Andrey, it seems to me that it is absolutely standard Django syntax. The problem is in defining the alias. Not the select_retaled syntax per se.

Comment: I tried what you say, just in case. But again ending up with the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9445805 that's standard syntax. Spanning relations using double underscore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126132/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-andrey-shipilov).